# Custom Taxonomy Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

i am new with the custom taxonomy. I installed a plugin called CPT and created a custom taxonomy called "Main Categories" which acting like a normal category. I am able to show the list of each main categories with the base url like:

`http://localhost/project/?main_categories=name`.

But, what i want to accomplish is :

`http://localhost/project/main_categories/term_id`.

Is there a way to do it? i tried several solution i found here but no luck.

I hope you guys could help me.

Thanks,

Comment: Set with permalink option from admin panel side

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i want the to keep the original base url for the original categories and posts. I only want to change it when using the `custom taxonomy url`.

Comment: you can try to use this plugin Custom Post Type Permalinks - https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Comment: i did. but it works only with custom post type but not with custom taxonomies, or im missing something? can you help me?